# can write OnClickListener into parceable?

Tags: java, android, save, onclicklistener, parcelable

Hello I have a trouble with OnClickListener

```
View.OnClickListener listener= new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) 
   { 
     Toast.makeText(Conversations.this, "click on  MSG", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  } 
};
```

========================================================================

I Need put this listener into Fragment which will parceable. 
I not parceableing listener but after readvalue is null and when click app crasher because it's reference on null object.

now I need find some methods which can use for save and read object (View.OnClickListener) if parceable or something similar. 
Without this I need rebuild my project  :(

Please Help me.

Thanks

_______________________________________________________--

I haven't have fragment in fragment I want all fragment put into "extra" and in other activity read from extra..

`Intent i= new Intent(Conversations.this,MessagesSingleFragmentActivity.cla‌​ss); i.putExtra("Fragment1", (Parcelable) recycleMessage); startActivity(i);`

and in other activity have

```
Intent extras = getIntent(); Fragment fragment = (Fragment) extras.getParcelableExtra("Fragment1"); fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No you cannot pass OnClickListener as Parcelable* but , if you want to observe click from one fragment to another , then you have to implement the onclick in second fragment.

**FragA.java:**// who have onClickListener

```
Runnable run;

public void setClick(Runnable run){
   this.run = run;
}

view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        // do something in onclick
        if(run!=null){run.run();}
    }
});
```

**FragB.java:**

```
((FragA)getParentFragment()).setClick(
       new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something in other fragment
            }
        }
)
```

**Updated:**

If you want to perform something onClick of **ActivityA** on **ActivityB** , then EventBus are best options for that use [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) by GreenBot

Comment: I haven't have fragment in fragment I want all fragment put into "extra" and in other activity read from extra.. 
 Intent i= new Intent(Conversations.this,MessagesSingleFragmentActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Fragment1", (Parcelable) recycleMessage);
                startActivity(i);
and in other activity have 
Intent extras = getIntent();
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) extras.getParcelableExtra("Fragment1");
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

Comment: fragments don't have extra's , pass an argument in fragment

Comment: I pass fragment into extra when call activity. but when in fragment OnClickListener, I don't know how parceable it.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to interact between fragments via Activity.. or more generally by interface which Activity conforms to.

One more thing: If you have common functionality in both fragments, maybe it is better to extract it to Activity?